# Создание анимации в SFML C++

Tags: c++, sfml

Покажите анимацию в sfml с постепенной сменой спрайтов заданной по определенному времени, к примеру каждые 0.5 секунд, всего 5 спрайтов progressbarzerospr,  progressbarhalfhalfspr, progressbarhalfspr, progressbarx2halfspr, progressbarfullspr, и как только переключились все 5 спрайтов, то завершаем переключение спрайтов и больше к нему не возвращаемся
Я сделал пример кода, но он не работает, подскажите где моя ошибка

```
    // Создаем массив спрайтов
    sf::Sprite sprites[5] = {
        sf::Sprite(waitlobby.progressbarzerospr),
        sf::Sprite(waitlobby.progressbarhalfhalfspr),
        sf::Sprite(waitlobby.progressbarhalfspr),
        sf::Sprite(waitlobby.progressbarx2halfspr),
        sf::Sprite(waitlobby.progressbarfullspr)
    };

    int currentSprite = 0; // текущий спрайт

    sf::Clock clock; // таймер
    float timePerFrame = 2.0f; // время между сменой спрайтов
    float timeSinceLastUpdate = 0.f; // время, прошедшее с последней смены спрайта
if (PLAYGAMELOBBY && weplaylevel) {
                    timeSinceLastUpdate += clock.restart().asSeconds();

                    // Если прошло достаточно времени для смены спрайта
                    if (timeSinceLastUpdate >= timePerFrame && currentSprite < 5)
                    {
                        timeSinceLastUpdate = 0.f;
                        sprites[currentSprite].setPosition(455.f, 856.f); // задаем позицию спрайту
                        currentSprite++; // увеличиваем номер текущего спрайта
                    }

                    // Рисуем текущий спрайт
                    if (currentSprite < 5)
                    {
                        win.draw(sprites[currentSprite]);
                        cout << "ХУЙ" << endl;
                    }
                    else {
                        weplaylevel = false;
                        loadlobbymousebutton = true;
                        PlayMenuButton = true; // Переставляем флаг на 1, так как вышли в главное меню и не находимся в меню Начать играть, чтобы не проверять на подсвечивание кнопки выхода из меню Начать играть в главное меню 
                        PLAYGAMELOBBY = false; // отрисовка нового меню закончена, проверяем заново и переставляем на false
                        isClicked = false; // чтобы не проверять на нажатие кнопок меню в самой игре 
                        weplaylevel = true;
                    }
                    win.display();
                }
            }
```